# How much internet is spent for each Restful request

Tags: android, rest, web

I am new to android and I'm developing a News application for just improving myself. The application loads news from a WordPress website using **Restful**. Here is the simple news model:

- Title
- News Description
- Category
- Date
- News Picture

For every new News, the application sends a request using Restful for new one(s) to **sync** data. Here is a case scenario that: the reader do not read all news, I mean from 20 News, just open 2 or 3 of them. To prevent data bundle consumption, I thought that just request for needed info like (**Title, Category, Data and Picture**) but, just **News Description** is remained (Not requested). While reader opens the news, then application sends request for opened News Description.
Here are two questions:

- Do you think if it is a correct approach that request for all news
  attributes apart from News Description? Doesn't it reduce the
  application performance or whatever?
- How much internet is spent for just News Description?

Please help me to improve my skill.
Thanks